# struct undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I'm very new to programming and I started to learn C. Now I just cant understand why my node structure is not visible to my functions.

I try to get some help on http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson7.html
but with no luck in using code blocks 13.12

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node  {
int data;
struct ptr * next;
};
struct node* head;

void Insert(int x)
{
struct node *temp;
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(head == NULL)
head = temp;
temp->data = x;
temp->data = x;
temp->next = NULL;
struct node* temp1 = head;
while(temp1-> != NULL;) {
temp1 = temp1->next;
}
temp1->next = temp;
}

void print() {
struct node* temp = head;
while(temp != NULL) {
printf("the data is %d", temp->data);
temp = temp->next;
}
}


int main ()
{
head = NULL;
int a,c;
printf("How many numbers ? : \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
for(i = 0; i<a; i++);  {
printf("Enter a number:\n");
scanf("%d",&c);
Insert(c);
print();
}

}
```

Comment: what is `struct ptr *next;`?

Comment: the line starting with `temp = ` is malformed: it misses a `);`

Comment: There are many errors, but no "struct undeclared (first use in this function)" was for C99.

Comment: please indent your code for readability.

Comment: `while(temp1->` points to what?

Comment: `i` is undeclared in your code.

Comment: Type `node*` is undefined in `temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`. use `struct node*` instead.

Comment: The semicolon in `while(temp1-> != NULL;)` is junk, and the last semicolon in `for(i = 0; i<a; i++);  {` may be junk.

Comment: NEVER cast the result of `malloc()`!

Comment: @PeterMiehle  Hahahaha SO community is so obsessed about that including me

Comment: fixed the syntax errors yet still get this message 'node' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: The undefinedness of `struct ptr` and `node` isn't fixed.

Comment: Other errors aren't fixed, too. Please show us the new code.

Comment: Do not edit the question after the answers have been posted with the intention to fix the errors that were in the question in the first place. This will invalidate the answers and make the question unhelpful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few lets go one by one

number 1

```
struct node  {
    int data;
    struct node *next;  // chagnge ptr -> node
};
```

number 2

```
struct node *temp;
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // struct node casting
```

number 3

```
while(temp1->next != NULL) {    // remove semi colum and put a next
    temp1 = temp1->next;
}
```

number 4

```
int i; // for while loop
for(i = 0; i<a; i++)  {
```

Now hopefully it compiles well, check runtime errors ( if any )

and yes

```
return 0; // just before main
```

Comment: Maybe you should delete the last semicolon in number 4 `for(i = 0; i<a; i++);  {` since it may cause unexpected behavior (prompting only once instead of `a` times)

Comment: And just remove the cast from `malloc()` completely :)

Comment: ok now its compiling but int the result it seems he print alot of garbage rather than the data of the the nodes

Comment: @kkk isn't since c99 **return 0** already included ? **int main(void){}** is enough.  The problem is when you do not specify the standard, then you need **return 0**. But when you specify **--std=c99** or **--std=c11** there is no need of **return 0**

Answer (score 0):

you are building an infinite loop with your first element:

```
temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(head == NULL)
  head = temp;

temp->data = x;
temp->next = NULL;
struct node* temp1 = head;
while(temp1->next != NULL) { // nothing to do
  temp1 = temp1->next;
}
temp1->next = temp; //temp is head and temp1 is head, so head->next points to head
```

you should do something like

```
if (head == NULL) {
   //fill head and leave
} else {
  //traverse to the last element and concatenate the new element
}
```